# What is the value for $\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{\sin x}{x}$?

Tags: calculus, limits, trigonometry

What is the value for $\lim \limits _{x\to\infty} \frac{\sin x} x$?

I solved it by expanding $\sin x$ as

$$\sin x = x - \frac {x^3} {3!} \dotsc$$

So $\lim \limits _{x\to\infty} \frac {\sin x} x = 1 -\infty = - \infty$,

but the answer is $0$. Why? What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Use [squeeze theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem) via $\frac{-1}{x}\le \frac{\sin x}{x}\le \frac{1}{x}$.  The specific error is that the Taylor series has both positive and negative terms, so you should be getting $1-\infty+\infty$, which is indeterminate.

Comment: The immediate reason you're mistaken is that $\sin(x)$ also equals $x - \frac{x^3}3 + \frac{x^5}{720} - \cdots$, so it's $1 - \infty + \infty - \cdots$, which cannot be decided using that approach.

Comment: Related question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/857532/limits-as-sinx-approaches-infinity

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes , the answer is $0$ .

One way to see this is by using the inequality :

$$\left |\frac{\sin x}{x}\right | \leq \frac{1}{x}$$ when $x>0$ (this happens because $|\sin x\ | \leq 1$ )

When $x \to \infty $ we have  $\frac{1}{x} \to 0$ so the limit must be $0$ .

Comment: I got the point . Thank you !

Answer (score 9):

The range of $\sin(x)$ will always be a value between -1 and 1, no matter what the input.  However, there is no such restriction on the denominator.  Therefore, if your numerator is restricted to a finite value, and your denominator is not, as the denominator goes to infinity the value of the whole expression will go to zero.